# I am getting configuration error on ASP.Net Webform application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on old website which was developed in ASP.Net webform and now i had to enable SSL for this website using Plesk.

After i enable SSL for from Plesk backend section of website started to show error. all backend files are under "backofficeCMS" folder.

It was working fine unless SSL was not enable once we enable SSL backend of this CMS started giving below error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainName.com\httpdocs\web.config    Line: 96

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.3928.0
```

Now i am not able to make it work even if i turn off  SSL Support
[image]

My web config file is same as it was, i am getting error for all folder which are protect by asp.net membership

```
<location path="backofficeCMS" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <trust level="Full" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

i get this error when i try to access any file in this folder `backofficeCMS`

it shows same error message for even a simple asp.net webform file as show below

Test.aspx File

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     WORKING
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea how this problem can be solved and any pointer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve issue after i removed
`<trust level="Full" />` from below code

```
<location path="backofficeCMS" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <trust level="Full" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I still dont have clue why it was working before SSL was not enable and why it created problem after enabling SSL support, any details about this issue could be helpful